# Any suggestions on efficient endless loop over all keys and all columns using pycassa?

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

If I issue:

```
colfam.get_range()
```

I get an iterator over all rows and columns as OrderedDict as

```
for rowkey, coldict in colfam.get_range()
```

However, if I just want the keys

```
for retval in colfam.get_range(column_count = 0)
    print retval[0]
    continue
```

I don't see anything printed.  Following does work, however:

```
for retval in colfam.get_range(start = 'x', end = 'x', column_count = 0)
    print retval[0]
    continue
```

(prints x correctly).

I read elsewhere that `get_range` with `column_count = 0` is supposed to produce a generator over keys only, am I wrong?

The problem I am facing is that some of the keys have large number of columns which cause the pycassa to timeout.  I was hoping to get a generator over keys, and then for every key, a xget over all rows.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I am sorry, but I figured it out (from another SO post.)  With column_count = 0, we need filter_empty = False, otherwise the generator really has no rows!  I am going to implement the loop next.  Sorry and thanks.